# Thunderbird configuration

Tags: server, email, thunderbird

I am creating one e-mail server in Ubuntu 16.04 with post-fix and dovecot. It's working fine. recently I am installing the Thunderbird and configure with in the server, it is also working fine, In outside of the server (another system) when I am installing the Thunderbird and configure with same user credentials its not working it showing the error username and password wrong. same user name and password is configured with in the server is working but outside (another system) its not working even that I am giving 777 permission for that user but no use . how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I'm trying to set up my email account in Thunderbird 
I entered the correct username and the correct password (I even changed the password and re entered it) but I still get that error.
"Configuration could not be verified - is your username or password wrong?"          please find the below links for reference https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1swznHmDQ8rZDVwaDhLbDlRYzQ/view?usp=sharing            https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1swznHmDQ8rNnBuRDNnTnlsd1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Which client setting did you use in Dovecot (for comparison with those in Thunderbird)? Also… POP3 in 2017 and no TLS/SSL? *\*shudder\**